# symfony filter for route

Tags: php, symfony

how i can filter for "type" on my results?

i need pass the type on route, and then get the result

```
 /**
    * @Rest\Get(path="/list/{type}/{page}")
    * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"list"}, serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks=true)
    */
   public function list(Request $request,PaginatorInterface $paginator, $page){

       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $repo= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Evento::class);
       $x= $repo->findBy([], ['tipo' =>'ASC']);

       $x= $paginator->paginate(
           $evento, 
           $request->query->getInt('page', $page), 
           99 
       );    

       return $x;

   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pass the type on route"? What keeps you from doing that?

Comment: Make it a parameter just like you did with `$page`...? I don't understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `type` and `page` are required (but it will be better to move query builder logic to the repository method)

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get(path="/list/{type}/{page}")
 * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"list"}, serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks=true)
 */
public function list(Request $request, PaginatorInterface $paginator, $type, $page) {
    $repo= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Evento::class);
    $qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('e');
    $qb->where('e.tipo = :type')
        ->setParameter('type', $type)
        ->orderBy('e.tipo', Criteria::ASC);

    $x= $paginator->paginate(
        $qb,
        $page,
        99
    );

    return $x;
}
```

if type and page are **not** required

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get(path="/list")
 * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"list"}, serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks=true)
 */
public function list(Request $request, PaginatorInterface $paginator) {
    $repo= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Evento::class);
    $qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('e');
    $qb->orderBy('e.tipo', Criteria::ASC);
    
    $x= $paginator->paginate(
        $qb,
        $request->query->getInt('p', 1),
        $request->query->getInt('l', 99),
        ['e.tipo']
    );

    return $x;
}
```

Url when not required: `/list?filterField=e.tipo&filterValue=some`

Comment: thanks for response,
why i get this fail:    
 "message": "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 40 near 'tipo = :tipo': Error: 'tipo' is not defined."

Comment: {typo} on my mysql is : tipo

Comment: i resolve with:

      $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Evento::class);
        $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $qb->select('p');
        $qb->where('p.tipo = :type');
        $qb->setParameter('type', $type);


        
        $x= $paginator->paginate(
            $qb,
            $page,
            4
        );
    
        return $x;